# Why Pythons eval() mistakes?

Tags: python, integer, eval

I need to solve some mathematical equations, something like below (but each time different formula):

```
formula="(2/10^8*x^2)+0.0131*x-1017.3-30"
```

where `x` is an integer.

I used eval() function to solve the problem. Function gave me an exception of:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'
```

I solved it like this:

```
formula=formula.replace('^','**')
```

Now, I encountered with another problem.

```
eval("2/10")
```

returns `0` instead I need `0.2`, as a result I get a wrong outcome.
I appreciate for any answer.

Comment: btw you do know `^` is for bitwise XOR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in Python 2.x `int / int` **always** returns an `integer`. Use Python 3 or explicitly write one of the arguments as a float, e.g. `2.0 / 10`, or (as Marjin Pieters reminds us), import the explicit Py3-like division behaviour as: `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: Or add `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed, thanks for mentioning, I always tend to forget that :)

Comment: @BasicWolf nvm I didn't see the second example. and he said `x` was an integer, but he must've lied. eg. `>>> x=5`
`>>> formula="(2/10^8*x^2)+0.0131*x-1017.3-30"`
`>>> eval(formula)`
`-1005.2344999999999` In Python 3 that doesn't work, anyway that's what I thought, when I saw the second example I realised OP lied